# Getting error ''element type is invalid expected a string'' with component import in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

There is any difference between **import Component from 'react'** or
**import React, {Component} from 'react'**? Im getting this error **element type is invalid expected a string** if I put this import **import React, {Component} from 'react'** but If I change to the other it's all ok. Its any problem with doing that? Thank you. Im new at coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Component from 'react'
```

is the same as

```
import React from 'react'
```

that's because you are importing the default export of the React package and you can name it as you wish.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

This "Component" refers to React.Component, you are importing "Component" from 'react' plus the default export.

imagine having a file with multiple export named exports.js

```js
const DefaultExport = () => null

export const OtherExport = () => null
export const AnotherExport = () => null

export default DefaultExport
```

You can import your component using

```
import something from './exports' //this is DefaultExport
import { OtherExport } from './exports' //OtherExport
import { AnotherExport as RandomExport } from './exports' //AnotherExport
import * as Exports from './exports' //you are importing all the exports
```

for the last case `import * as Exports from './exports'` you can access and use all the exports from the file, such as

```
Exports.default //refer to default export
Exports.OtherExport //refer to OtherExport
Exports.AnotherExport //refer to AnotherExport
```

Answer (score 0):

What i do is :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

then you can use it in class like:

```
class Login extends Component
```

the usage of {Component} is nothing but you are destructuring the import ,

Like if you would have done :

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

thenyou would have used it like :

```
class Login extends React.Component
```

Thats the difference, hope it helps.

Feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

Component is not exported by default from react, so you need to import it with destructuring